# HTML 5 MIC to MIC connection

Tags: html, web, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Is it possible to have two or more microphones to talk to each other - something like Chatroulette but only mics with use of HTML5 audio capture API? Maybe someone have links with examples where this type of thing working. Sorry but no idea where to ask this type of question.

Comment: how do MIC talk to one another, it is input device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) and you should also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet/12855533#12855533).